# OSX Application Beta Testers?

Tags: applications, development, websites

Is there a website, platform, to find beta testers for OSX applications?

Comment: The folks at Stack Exchange/Overflow were developing a platform for that. See [this question on Meta Ask Different](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/643/updated-are-you-interested-in-beta-testing-os-x-and-ios-apps).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**MacDeveloper.net**](http://macdeveloper.net)

From their [About page](http://macdeveloper.net/about):

> MacDeveloper helps companies and individual software developers alike improve the quality of their products by providing a platform to have their applications properly tested from a well informed, and energetic Beta Pool.

Comment: Looked good, but then I saw you have to pay. Not worth it right now for the value of my app.

Comment: I've only tried on the "tester" side. How much is it to post an app?

Answer (score 1):

I would engage people over twitter. It's even harder work attracting the right beta testers than it is being a good beta tester.

Answer (score 1):

There is a platform by Stack Exchange. From [Abby Miller's post](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/643/updated-are-you-interested-in-beta-testing-os-x-and-ios-apps):

> We've got a community of talented iOS and OS X developers hanging out on Stack Overflow, and a committed community of power users and enthusiasts hanging out here on Ask Different. Doesn't it seem natural to provide a way to help people interested in testing new software and developers in need of alpha and beta testers find each other?

This program will match developers with potential testers. See the post above for more information and to sign up for the program.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Amazon's [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) to set up some test scenarios (as "HITs" - Human Intelligence Tasks) if you're willing to shell out a couple ducats.